# How to test android application by client in meantime of development?

Tags: android, distribution, apk

Hi i am new to android development.
 I am creating one application. I need to send sample application to client for testing purpose.
In iPhone development we can send .ipa file to client using TestFlightApp. Is there any way to do this similar way for Android application testing.

Please help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

each time you build your application, an apk file is created in your project's bin folder. you can use that file for testing purposes

Comment: how to send this file to my client. Can i direct mail to client? Is he can direct run application in its android device?

Comment: yes, the client needs to save it on internal memory, and then run the APK from it (by using ASTRO or some other preferred file explorer)

Comment: Thanks for respond. Do not feel bad to me what is meant by ASTRO? I dont know exactly wha it is?

Comment: it is just an app which can be used to browse the filesystem of your device

Comment: Just a side note: install non-market app requires tick a setting on device `Settings -> Applications -> Unknown sources`.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your application project folder

Scroll down to Android tools

click on : Export as signed Android application

Use the debug key located on your sdk folder to sign the app
,the password's key : android

and you will get a debug signed apk ready to install on any device .

To keep track of your apks you may create a string variable and use it as build tag so you don't get confused by multiple apks .

I'm doing so on my project , you can also create an unsigned apk but I don't know if you will be able to install it on a real device .

Some use maven to build the apk but it's more complicated .